# search filter in angular with paging

Tags: angular, angular-pagination

> Html component

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" (change)="searchText($event)"/>

<li *ngFor="let list of this.lists | paginate: { itemsPerPage: count, currentPage: p,totalItems:4 } index as i"><a href="javascript:void(0)"> # {{ i+count * (p - 1) + 1 }} List </a></li>
```

.ts file

```
  searchText(text_string:any)
   {
    this.lists  = this.lists.filter(item => item.id === text_string.target.value);
   }
```

I want to display only those items where id matches this id `{{ i+count * (p - 1) + 1 }}`

Any solution to implement search in the existing paging

Comment: what not working here ? Can you be more specific about it ? Thanks!

Comment: @GRD Searching is not working i want when i type any number in text field it should match with `{{ i+count * (p - 1) + 1 }}` this row value and display only that particular record or suppose if there is 1 in text field it should display record where  `{{ i+count * (p - 1) + 1 }}`  this value contains 1

Answer (score 0):

First you need two variables: "listFiltered" and "list", else you loose "this.list" (if you change the search you filter over the list filtered), so

```
searchText(text_string:any)
{
    if (!text_string)
       this.listFiltered=this.lists
    else
       this.listsFiltered  = this.lists.filter(
                item => item.id === text_string.target.value);
}
```

To paginate, generall you has two variables: pageIndex (from 0 to ...) and pageSize (the number of elements). So you can use [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe)

```
<li *ngFor="let list of listsFiltered |
                   slice:pageIndex*pageSize:(pageIndex+1)*pageSize">
...
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks will it work with paging because in my code paging is already there i have to add search functionality and i want to compare with `{{ i+count * (p - 1) + 1 }}` this value not with id one can you please let me know how to solve this issue